# Salesforce Price Rule Pro-Rating Scenarios Based on Subscription Start Date/End Date Not Calculating as Expected

Tags: cpq, pricerule

We created some pro-rating scenarios via Price Rules. The price rules are for a specific price book and based on Subscription start and end Dates.

**Here are all of the scenarios but we tested on the scenario under #2:**

1. Starting after 6/30/2020 and forward there will be no discount for all products in the XYZ Price Book
2. Starting 11/1/2019 there will be a 33.33% discount for all products in the XYZ Price Book and the default term would be 8 (start date equals 11/1/2019 and end date date equals 6/30/2020)
3. Starting 12/1/2019 there will be a 33.33% discount for all products in the XYZ Price Book and the default term would be 7 (start date equals 12/1/2019 and end date date equals 6/30/2020)
4. Starting 1/1/2020 there will be a 33.33% discount for all products in the XYZ Price Book and the default term would be 6 (start date equals 1/1/2020 and end date date equals 6/30/2020)
5. Starting 2/1/2020 there will be a 33.33% discount for all products in the XYZ Price Book and the default term would be 5 (start date equals 2/1/2020 and end date date equals 6/30/2020)
6. Starting 3/1/2020 there will be a 66.67% discount for all products in the XYZ Price Book and the default term would be 4 (start date equals 3/1/2020 and end date date equals 6/30/2020)
7. Starting 4/1/2020 there will be a 66.67% discount for all products in the XYZ Price Book and the default term would be 3 (start date equals 4/1/2020 and end date date equals 6/30/2020)
8. Starting 5/1/2020 there will be a 66.67% discount for all products in the XYZ Price Book and the default term would be 2 (start date equals 5/1/2020 and end date date equals 6/30/2020)
9. Starting 6/1/2020 there will be a 66.67% discount for all products in the XYZ Price Book and the default term would be 1 (start date equals 6/1/2020 and end date date equals 6/30/2020)

**Here is how the price rule is built:**

[image]
[image]

**When testing the scenario we completed these steps when adding a product to a quote:**

1. Original Dates set upon quote creation of 7/1/2020 through 6/30/2021. And saved. No discount applied - Perfect
2. Within the Quote Line Editor we changed the dates to be 11/1/2019 through 6/30/2020 and saved. Expecting the above price rule to fire. It does and applies appropriate discount of 33.33% and sets the default subscription term to 8 - Perfect
3. Within the Quote Line Editor we changed the dates to be 7/1/2019 through 6/30/2020 and saved. Expecting the discount to be removed and default subscription term set back to 12 and price set back to the list price. Result was that the Pricing increased and discount still showed in the Quote Line Editor. Here is the screenshot of the products in the quote line editor (the 3rd product is not subscription but the first two are). The first product discount removed but the Net Unit Price and Net Total are more than list price. The second product discount remained and the Net Unit Price and the Net Total are more than the list price.
   [image]

**Here is how the Product is setup in the price book:**

[image]

**Here is the Quote Line Result after the 3 steps above were completed:**

[image]

What are we doing wrong? Is this not the correct way to setup pro-rate scenarios?
It was suggested that we apply the discount to the non-prorated list unit price, and we put that value into "Special Price" (another non-prorated field). That way the system calculates the proration for you with the end result being "Regular Price" (special price times prorate multiplier). If we were to do do this route, would it be a Process Builder with the following field updates for updating the Special Price filed with the list unit price, updating the default term? Where would you place the discount (as in what field)?

Any direction on troubleshooting or correction would be terrific. Apologies for the wordiness just wanted to try to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: We have resolved this issue.

Comment: Updates had to be made to the Price Conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by making adjustments within the price conditions where the dates are referenced. Instead of Greater or Equals and Less or Equal the criteria was changed to Equals.